# Jquery mobile, pagination

Tags: javascript, variables, jquery-mobile

I'm making a simple comments page for a mobile site. The trouble I have is I am trying to make my fixed header show what posts are showing. so 1-6 on the first page, 7-12 on the next.

This is all to be triggered with a swipe left or right to the next page will add 6 to the variables.

The trouble I have is the variables are resetting to their original set value.

How do I get the variables to add and decrease with the 2 functions without resetting.

```
$(document).on('pageinit', function(event){

var currentStart = 1;
var currentEnd = 6;

  $('div.ui-page').on("swipeleft", function () {
    var nextpage = $(this).next('div[data-role="page"]');
      if (nextpage.length > 0) {
        $.mobile.changePage(nextpage, { transition: "slide"},"slide", false, true);
        currentStart += 6;
        currentEnd += currentEnd + 6;
        $('#currentStart').empty().append(currentStart);
        $('#currentEnd').empty().append(currentEnd);

      }
  });

  $('div.ui-page').on("swiperight", function () {
    var prevpage = $(this).prev('div[data-role="page"]');
    if (prevpage.length > 0) {
      $.mobile.changePage(prevpage, { transition: "slide", reverse: true }, true, true);
      currentStart = currentStart - 6;
      currentEnd = currentEnd - 6;
      $('#currentStart').empty().append(currentStart);
      $('#currentEnd').empty().append(currentEnd);
    }
  });
```

So every time you swipe left or right the `currentStart` will increment up by 6 or decrease by 6, however everytime you swipe the variables are resetting to their original declaration.

How do I stop that?

Comment: I see that you are setting the variable values to their defaults within a pageinit function.  Maybe if you move those statements outside the pageinit all would be well?

Comment: `$(document).on('pageinit', function(event){` this will fire on each and every page but one time per each. Each time you visit a "new page" you run the same code. you need to delegate it to specific page(s) `$(document).on('pageinit', "#pageID", function(event){`

Comment: Thanks guys, I'm new to Jquery mobile and scrambling something together. Much appreciated it works great now.